# Primes of the form $x^3+y^3+z^3 - 3xyz$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Do quadruplets $(x,y,z,p)$ of positive integers exist for which $p$ is a prime number and $$x^3+y^3+z^3 = 3xyz + p?$$ 
I've tried looking for solutions in mathematica for $x,y,z<1000$, without finding any. Unfortunately, looking at the equation $\mod 3$ or $\mod 9$ has yielded no result. Is there anyone who can help? Thanks.

EDIT: I just discovered a fatal flaw in my mathematica code. vrugtehagel rightfully pointed out that $8^3+8^3+7^3 - 3\cdot8\cdot8\cdot7 = 23$ is a valid solution to this problem.

Comment: Your cubic factors.

Comment: You're right but how can you be sure that not one of your factors equal 1?

Comment: $$ x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz = (x+y+z)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - yz - zx - xy). $$ The quadratic factor is positive semidefinite, we can write it as $r^2 + rs + s^2$ with $r=x-y, \; s = y-z.$ The quadratic could also be written as $$ \left( (x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2 \right) / 2$$

Comment: Oh, primes $p = x^3 + 2 y^3 + 4 z^3 - 6xyz$ are much, much more interesting. Oh, and requiring the variables positive throws off everything.

Comment: Interesting... Would my problem still be solvable if x, y and z are no longer required to be positive I wonder

Comment: Take, say, $$ 500 \geq |x| \geq |y| \geq |z| $$ and see what happens.

Comment: I had to abort my evaluation fairly quickly. To leave a little impression of what happened: {-500,-500,-499}, {-500,6,495}, {-500,7,494}, ...

Comment: It appears you've made a mistake in you code - $(x,y,z,p)=(8,7,8,23)$ is a solution

Comment: There are infinite such solutions: if $p=3k-1$ then $(x,y,z)=(k,k-1,k)$.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. Thanks

Comment: Umm, $(n,n,n+1)$ gives $3n+1,$ then $(n,n+1,n+1)$ gives $3n+2.$ Not sure whether you can get the prime $3$

Comment: I would say "valid" rather than "legal".

Comment: Since the cubic factors to 2 positive forms and x+y+z>1, the value is prime iff the second factor equals 1 and x+y+z is prime. Equivalently x,y,z are, in some order, n,n,n-1 or n, n, n+1, and p=3n-1 or p=3n+1 is prime.

Comment: [All ordered positive solutions below $100$](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LnHxT.png).

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579310/two-questions-involving-x3y3z3-3xyz-factorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${x}^{3}-3\,y\,z\,x+{z}^{3}+{y}^{3}=\left( x+z+y\right) \,\left( {x}^{2}-z\,x-y\,x+{z}^{2}-y\,z+{y}^{2}\right) $$

$${x}^{2}-z\,x-y\,x+{z}^{2}-y\,z+{y}^{2}=1$$

if x,y,z - consecutive terms in http://oeis.org/A004526

then $p=3\,n+1,p=3\,n+2$

Answer (score 2):

We use the identity
$$x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz = (x+y+z)\left( \frac{ (x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2 }{2}\right)$$
to try to find some solutions using linear and quadratic equations with the following system:
$$\begin{cases}x+y+z=1\\(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2=2p\end{cases}$$
Putting   $z=1-x-y$ one gets 
$$(x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2=2(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2(xy+xz+yz)=2p\Rightarrow 3(x^2+y^2+xy-x-y)+1=p$$
We look for primes in the arithmetic progression $\{3n+1\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ so we get the equation $$x^2+y^2+xy-x-y=n$$ and we look for integer points in ellipses.

We look at the six first  primes $p=7,13,19,31,37,43$ of the form $3n+1$ corresponding to $n=2,4,6,10,12,14$ respectively. 
$$x^2+y^2+xy-x-y=2\qquad (*)$$
Solutions $(x,y)=(0,-1),(2,-1),(2,0)$ yield  the solution $(x,y,z)=(2,-1,0)$ giving an example for
$$x^3+y^3+z^3-xyz=7$$
$$x^2+y^2+xy-x-y=4\qquad (**)$$
Solutions $(x,y)= (1,\pm2),(2,-2)$ yield the solutions $(x,y,z)=(1,\pm 2,\mp 2),(2,-2,1)$ giving examples for $$x^3+y^3+z^3-xyz=13$$

$$x^2+y^2+xy-x-y=6\qquad (***)$$  Solutions $(x,y)=(0,-2),(3,-2),(3,0)$ leads to examples for $p=19$.

Similarly $$x^2+y^2+xy-x-y=10, 12, 14\qquad (****)$$  admit respectively the solutions
$\{(-1,-2),(4,-2),(4,-1)\},\{(0,-3),(4,-3),(4,0)\}$  and $\{(2,-4),(3,-4),(3,2)$ which give solutions for 
$$x^3+y^3+z^3-xyz=31,37\space \text{and} \space 43$$
FINAL NOTE.- I wanted just to exhibit some examples of solutions like the case $p=23$ given by the O.P.(note that prime $23=3\cdot 7+2$ it is not of the form $3n+1$). However I add a question and a pertinent quote to finish.

►“It is very difficult to prove the non-existence of integer solutions of the general equation
$$ax^3+by^3+cz^3-dxyz=0”\space \text{(L.J.Mordell)}$$

►Is there always solution for $x^3+y^3+z^3-xyz=p$ when $p=3n+1$? (*for the first 6 examples of such primes, I have found without difficulty solutions*).